# Modify data extracted from rss file with simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

I am extracting data from an rss file using simplexml. The urls in  are wrong and I am trying to change them.
To be able to use the data, I need to strip everything before the word "base" in those urls.

I can do it with the following:

```
<?php echo strstr($rss->channel->item[0]->link, 'base') ?: $rss->channel->item[0]->link;?>
<?php echo strstr($rss->channel->item[1]->link, 'base') ?: $rss->channel->item[1]->link;?>
<?php echo strstr($rss->channel->item[2]->link, 'base') ?: $rss->channel->item[2]->link;?>
etc...
```

but its looks messy and I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it more efficiently without having to call the strstr function over and over again.

I tried many things and the following gave me the best result:

```
foreach($rss->channel->item->link as $b)
{
$new_url[] = strstr($b, 'base') ?: $b;
}
```

but when I call it with:

```
<?php echo $new_url[0];?>
<?php echo $new_url[1];?>
<?php echo $new_url[2];?>
```

it only works on the first instance.

Any idea? Or am I completely wrong about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `foreach($rss->channel->item->link as $b)` will give the link in `$b`

The items have a link property, so in that case you can loop the items.

The code could be

```
foreach($rss->channel->item as $b)
{
    $new_url[] = strstr($b->link, 'base') ?: $b->link;
}
```

Note that using [strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

> Returns the portion of string, or false if needle is not found.

If the strstr returns false, you add `$b->link` to the array, which might of type `SimpleXMLElement`.

You might cast it to a string `(string)$b->link` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

in the top example you are iterate over the items ... in the foreach you are tying it iterate over links